# Keyboard's clear button doesn't work when changing the text using TextEditingController

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a TextFormField and a button. When I change the text in textfield using the TextEditingController (as a result of pressing the button). the keyboard's default clear button does not work.

```
        TextFormField(
          controller: textController,
          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
          decoration: InputDecoration(counterText: ""),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
          inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
            WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
          ],
        ),
        FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            textController.text = '34';
          },
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
```

Did anyone encounter this problem. Please help, thanks.